# Find next coulmn checkbox state when user clicks on checkbox in wijmo

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, row, wijmo, c1flexgrid

My Code is like below, I have a json like below, when the json object have PQ then PQ column check box should be checked and when the json object have FG then FG column check box should be checked. Now when user wants to update a row then how will I know that row values after update (check box updations) . How to catch next column checkbox state? I mean each and every time when user checks a checkbox then I should take all the row values and form json to send data to server. How Can I achieve this

```
                 [{
                        "id": 1001,
                        "name": "TC1",
                        "usedIn": ["PQ"]
                    }, {
                        "id": 1002,
                        "name": "TC2",
                        "usedIn": ["PQ","FG"]
                    }, {
                        "id": 1003,
                        "name": "TC2",
                        "usedIn": ["FG"]
                    }];



 <wj-flex-grid auto-height="" allow-resizing="Both" additional-height="40" selection-mode="Row" is-read-only="false" items-source="vm.technicalCritrions" control="vm.flex" item-formatter="itemFormatter">
                        <wj-flex-grid-column header="PQ" width="*" binding="usedIn">
                            <wj-flex-grid-cell-template cell-type="Cell">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="$item.usedIn.indexOf('PQ')>-1" ng-click="vm.PQ($item,$event,$row,$col,vm.flex)" />
                            </wj-flex-grid-cell-template>
                        </wj-flex-grid-column>
                        <wj-flex-grid-column header="FG" width="*" binding="usedIn">
                            <wj-flex-grid-cell-template cell-type="Cell">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="$item.usedIn.indexOf('FG')>-1" ng-click="vm.FG($item,$event,$row,$col,vm.flex)" />
                            </wj-flex-grid-cell-template>
                        </wj-flex-grid-column>
                        <wj-flex-grid-column format="D" binding="id" width="*"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                        <wj-flex-grid-column header="{{'global.titles.name' | translate}}" binding="name" width="*">
                            <b>{{$item.name}}</b>
                        </wj-flex-grid-column>
                    </wj-flex-grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "cellEditEnded" event to detect user edits, including checkbox changes. The event provides parameters that indicate which row and column were edited.

For example, this code detects edits and logs some information to the console if the property that was edited was of type "Boolean" (a checkbox):

```
 $scope.cellEditEnded = function(s, e) {
      var flex = s, // FlexGrid is the event sender
          row = flex.rows[e.row], // row that was edited
          col = flex.columns[e.col]; // column that was edited

      // do something with the data object that was changed
      if (col.dataType == wijmo.DataType.Boolean) {
          console.log('you changed the value of the "' + 
               col.binding + '" property for this object: ');
          console.log(JSON.stringify(row.dataItem));
      }
 }
```

You can see how this works in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/Lwdxkcow/